# What happens to a Uniswap transaction with an invalid token address

Tags: transactions

I am wondering what happens in a `swapExactETHForTokens()` transaction, when the address of the token you want to swap for is invalid. Of course, you will not receive a token, but do you also lose what you want to pay? At what stage does the exchange validate the token address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually not so much of a transaction question, but a question about Uniswap code.

Uniswap will basically cast the given address to an ERC20 interface, after which it assumes it has ERC20 functionality. After that it calls the address's `transferFrom` function - but since that doesn't exist, the transaction will be reverted. So you will only lose some gas costs, but not anything else.